# How perspective of two competing stakeholders are captured in sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I am training a sentiment analysis model using tweepy and textBlob. I came across an interesting instance in which the sentiment of a statement can be affected by the position of stakeholder. Wondering how sentiment analysis works in such case

> RT @Pehla_Trade: #Rupee strengthened by 14 paise to 64.34 against the US #dollar in early trade at the Interbank Foreign Exchange market
>
> Sentiment(polarity= -0.012499999999999997, subjectivity=0.2125)

In the above statement the polarity of sentiment is -ve, but as a reader, I feel the value should be positive instead

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are using analyses the text, regardless of the opinion holder. In this case you need a knowledge base to specify the holder, and alter the sentiment based on who says what. For example, in the finance domain, "The Rupee has reached a good level against the US Dollar" would be positive to an Indian opinion holder, but negative to an American. If you have a handful of opinion holders (e.g., a few Twitter users), then you could manually add some rules to tweak the sentiment based on the holder.